# close bootstrap drop down Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a bootstrap dropdwon , i need it only open and close  when press in  `'li.dropdown a'` and close when i press on the body .. 
i make it when open and close from only click in the icon . but need the code that make me close it when i click in the body .

**open and close with icon ( Working ) :**

```
$('li.dropdown a').on('click', function (event) {
               $('li.dropdown.setting-widget').toggleClass("open");
    });
```

**** close when i click in body  (not Working ) :****

```
    if (!$('li.dropdown.setting-widget').hasClass("open")) {
     $('body').on('click', function (event) {
               $('li.dropdown.setting-widget').toggleClass("open");
    });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the toggleClass to "closed"?

Comment: @alex , their is no class call close !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the context is correct, this code should work.

Your if statement needs to be inside the method.

```
$('body').on('click', function (event) {
  if ($('li.dropdown.setting-widget').hasClass("open")) {
      $('li.dropdown.setting-widget').toggleClass("open");
  }
});
```

If it does not work, you should add more context like some example HTML, or a JS fiddle showing the problem.

Comment: I removed the ! in the if statement try it now. I missed it before. I tested it on my bootstrap site, Changing the context of the target of course, and it worked.